# Application shown but not responsive for up to 5 seconds prior to calling applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: ios, iphone, performance

While attempting to optimize load speed I started placing timers in different places and looking at the performance.  The app uses OpenGL and Core Data and has a decent amount of screens and artwork.

But the largest part of the lag seems to be taking place prior to applicationWillEnterForeground (assuming it's not a cold load)

The app shows up and is displayed and the UI is unresponsive for close to 5 seconds. I start a timer and print a time as soon as I can press a button. The time between applicationWillEnterForeground and when I can press the button is 200 milliseconds.

What can be causing my application to be slow to load prior to applicationWillEnterForeground or what can I do evaluate what is happening there? Instruments does not seem to display any information about that part of the launch.

Other testing app I have don't seem the same performance. Is it the bundle size or the amount of memory used by the application? Loading dynamic libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to OpenAL.  The app was not closing the OpenAL context and for some reason this caused considerable problems when closing and reloading the app. The app uses CosCos Denshion so I to make sure to call these.

```
  [CDAudioManager end];
  [SimpleAudioEngine end];
```